Excel Solver VBA not satisfying constraints
I’m working on a project with a 30-year time horizon, where I aim to determine the specific net margin for each year. The net margins are located in cells C59 to AF59, corresponding to each of the 30 years, and I want to achieve these by adjusting the annual revenues (C61 to AF61). I’ve set target net margin in cell C60, which remains constant throughout the entire period and spans to AF60. I am calling solver from sheet Core data, whereas solver and inputs for solver are located in sheet Economic data.
However, when I run Solver, the resulting revenues yield net margins that deviate from the target value (see photo below). Interestingly, when I manually execute Solver, it works perfectly. I attempted to address the issue by using e.g. FormulaText:="=C60", as I saw suggested elsewhere, but this didn’t resolve the problem.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any ideas on how to solve this?
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheets("Economic data").Activate
    
    Me.CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(255, 242, 204)
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    SolverReset
       
    SolverOk SetCell:="$C$59", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="$C$61:$AF$61", Engine:=1


    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$C$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$D$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$E$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$F$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$G$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$H$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$I$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$J$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$K$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$L$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$M$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$N$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$O$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$O$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$P$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$P$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$Q$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$Q$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$R$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$R$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$S$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$S$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$T$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$U$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$U$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$V$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$V$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$W$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$W$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$X$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$X$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$Y$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$Y$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$Z$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$Z$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AA$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$AA$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AB$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$AB$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AC$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$AC$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AD$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$AD$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AE$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$AE$60"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AF$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=$AF$60"

    SolverOptions MaxTime:=900, AssumeNonNeg:=True

    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    Sheets("Core data").Activate
End Sub



Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need a self contained Minimum Reproducible Example to be able to comment reliably, but there are plenty of fairly simple optimisation problems that Solver fails to get a correct answer to. The authors of Solver will try to sell you a better version for a high price. Try invoking it manually and recording a macro that might just show you where your VBA code is going wrong.
